# ¿Como puedo excluir directorios o archivos al depurar en VSCode con Xdebug un sistema PHP?

Tags: php, vscode, xdebug

Estoy usando Visual Studio Code para depurar (*o debuggear*) usando Xdebug un sistema hecho en PHP.

Todo funciona bien, el problema viene cuando ocurren `Notices`, `Warnings`, etc. en el código fuente de las librerias (*o vendors*).

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedeo hacer para excluir esos archivos o directorios mientras estoy depurando?

Este es mi archivo `launch.json`

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003,
      "xdebugSettings": {
        "max_data": -1,
        "max_children": 100,
        "max_depth": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente pude dedicarle un tiempo a resolver este tema y encontré que la extensión [**PHP Debug**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug) dentro del archivo `launch.json` brinda la posibilidad de agregar la configuración `ignore`.

> `ignore`: una matriz opcional de patrones globales de los que se deben ignorar los errores (por ejemplo, `**/vendor/**/*.php`)

#### Solución:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003,
      "ignore": [
        "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/**/*.php" # Ejemplo
      ],
      "xdebugSettings": {
        "max_data": -1,
        "max_children": 100,
        "max_depth": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```